# PieChart DevExpress recarga la pagina en vez de exportar archivos PNG, JPEG, Etc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, devexpress

Tengo un problema para exportar un Pie Chart de DevExpress a archivos PNG, JPEG, etc. cuando le doy a exportar, me recarga la pantalla.

```javascript
pieChart = $("#pie").dxPieChart({
            size: {
                width: 500
                },
                palette: 'bright',
            dataSource: PieResumen,
            legend:
            {
                orientation: 'horizontal',
                itemTextPosition: 'right',
                horizontalAlignment: 'bottom',
                verticalAlignment: 'right',
                columnCount: 4,
            },
            series:
                [
                    {
                        argumentField: "etiqueta",
                        valueField: "presupuesto",
                        label: {
                            visible: true,
                            connector: { visible: true, width: 2 },
                            customizeText(arg) { return `${arg.value.toLocaleString(undefined, {                minimumFractionDigits: 2 })} ; ${arg.percentText}`; },
                        },
                    }],
            title: "Presupuesto Gastos Administrativos",
            export: {
                enabled: true,
            },
            onPointClick(e) {
                const point = e.target;

                toggleVisibility(point);
            },
            onLegendClick(e) {
                const arg = e.target;

                toggleVisibility(this.getAllSeries()[0].getPointsByArg(arg)[0]);
            },

            }).dxPieChart("instance");

        function toggleVisibility(item) {
            if (item.isVisible()) {
                item.hide();
            } else {
                item.show();

            }
        }
    }
```

Busqué el mismo procedimiento en otras pantallas para comparar, y todo parece estar bien, y no encuentro documentación que me ayude a resolver este inconveniente. No salta ningún tipo de error.